# Is there a way to "save" images drawn using canvasAPI to reduce lag?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, html5-canvas, lag

I am using CanvasAPI in my program. My game has a lot of character sprites so I want to save them as an "image" in my program so I can use them again later and not need to make the computer render them over and over.

I tried using getImageData() and putImageData() but I found out that using those functions can cause alot of lag.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.